# What does Kylo Ren's helmet actually do?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In the sequel movie The Force Awakens, Han Solo confronts Kylo Ren on a narrow catwalk across a chasm, and demands:

> Ben, take off that mask! you don't need it!

Indeed, he is clearly not dependent on it as we frequently see him without his helmet for extended periods.

[image: Helmetless Kylo]

We know that Kylo Ren models himself on his ancestor Darth Vader, and hiding his face behind an intimidating mask is consistent with this. It could easily be thought that his helmet is nothing more than a scary-looking accessory.

However whenever he does remove his helmet there is a hiss of gas escaping indicating that it is at higher than ambient air pressure. Therefore his helmet seems to have some functional purpose. Does it supply oxygen to him at higher pressure or concentration, to reduce fatigue during lightsabre battles? Does the eyepiece act as a heads-up display or enhance his vision in some way, e.g. by making the infrared spectrum visible to him?

What does Kylo Ren's helmet do in a functional sense?

Edit: I'm not asking why he wears a helmet/mask, as it's pretty clear that the real reason is to look scary.

My question is whether the helmet has a function / justification *apart* from the intimidation factor, and if so what it could be.

Comment: Embedded vocoder, and had a mechanical apparatus to revive the mask, bit that's it. https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kylo_Ren%27s_helmet

Comment: does this help? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6EsDzjyy65I

Comment: Look... vaguely... like Darth Vader...?

Comment: [It's just that it's terribly comfortable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HnvQM465zM). I think everyone will be wearing one in the future.

Comment: It makes him look ridiculous, according to Snoke.

Comment: @Batperson - This is materially the same question as the one proposed as a duplicate. If Ren's helmet does have a function / justification other than the intimidation factor (or just looking cool), then that'd presumably be at least one of the reasons why he wears it. The fact that none of the answers to the other question have identified a function / justification other than intimidation and aesthetics may be because there is no canonical information on any other functions. In which case, you're unlikely to get any answers here that are more informative than the ones provided there.

Comment: And if it so happens that there is relevant evidence out there on other functions, which wasn't posted in the other thread, then it _should_ be posted in the other thread, since it'd be very relevant to that question. If you don't manage to get this thread reopened, you might want to consider placing a bounty on the other thread, with the stipulation that you're looking for evidence of functions other than intimidation and aesthetics.